# Issue with iCTNet2 installation

Tags: software-installation, cytoscape

Has anyone encountered this same installation issue of iCTNet2?

I encountered this issue for installation of iCTNet2 via Cytoscape App Manager and similarly via installation from website download/install page.

I tried both installations via Cytoscape and via website takes a long time, when both is still installing even 4 hours later, I cancelled the installation. Does it really take that long? Or I should just wait for more than 4hrs to install this?

Any recommendations please? Thank you.

[image]